# HTML Checkbox function into PHP output

Tags: php, html

I have a function that takes in 2 params ($group, $array)

$group = the 'name' of the input attribute
$array = the array of checkbox values

```
function checkboxes($group, $array) {
    $string = NULL;
    $group = (string)$group."[]";
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $string .= "<br /><input type='checkbox' id=".$value." name='".$group."'        value='".$value."' /><label for=".$value.">$value</label>";
    }
    return $string;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is convert that into proper HTML, so that I can process the value in a script.

here is the input:

```
checkboxes("class", array("Warrior","Mage","Priest","Rogue"));


$boxes = $_POST['class'];
for ($i=0; $i<count($boxes); $i++) {
    echo $boxes[$i];
}
```

Output: "R" (when more than one are checked as well)

Any help would be great, sorry if I forgot anything.

This is homework, so don't give me answers that break the stackoverflow terms/my schools honor code please!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, `checkboxes("class", array("Warrior","Mage","Priest","Rogue"));` already outputs html code with `class` as  array ..

Comment: No, it doesn't output anything. It returns a concatenated string containing the HTML needed to make that array into a form acceptable html statement

Comment: I just tested your code and works flawless ..

Comment: Did you check more than one option? I'm only getting one of the checkboxes

Comment: yes, got all options selected.

Comment: he wants the values of checkboxes, not html of checkboxes

Comment: @Ninsuo what did you think I was talking about?

Comment: Wow, I reloaded the page and it suddenly works. It literally didn't work before that, and I didn't tweak the code. What the crap

Comment: How in the world are **we** supposed to know what does and does not break your school's honor code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It seems to print all checked boxes.

```
<?php
function checkboxes($group, $array) {
    $string = NULL;
    $group = (string)$group."[]";
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $string .= "<br /><input type='checkbox' id=".$value." name='".$group."'        value='".$value."' /><label for=".$value.">$value</label>";
    }
    return $string;
}

if( isset( $_POST[ 'class' ] ) ) {
    $boxes = $_POST['class'];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($boxes); $i++) {
        echo $boxes[$i] . '<br />';
    }

}
?>
<form action="t23.php" method="POST">
    <?php
    echo checkboxes("class", array("Warrior","Mage","Priest","Rogue"));
    ?>
    <input type="submit"  name="btnOutput" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: How he can do that since `$_POST['class']` is `class[]` ?

Comment: I did that too, that simply outputs "Rogue" (the last entity in the array). It's echoed inside a form too

Comment: @MihaiIorga - That's how you handle array variables in PHP.

Comment: aaa yes, *You can directly print the value of `$_POST['class']`* - I don't see you printing directly the value of `$_POST['class']`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your arrangement is in you page but:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['class'])){
        echo 'SELECTED: <br /><br />';
        $boxes = $_POST['class'];
        for ($i=0; $i<count($boxes); $i++) {
            echo $boxes[$i].'<br />';
        }

    }

    function checkboxes($group, $array) {
        $string = NULL;
        $group = (string)$group."[]";
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $string .= "<br /><input type='checkbox' id=".$value." name='".$group."'        value='".$value."' /><label for=".$value.">$value</label>";
        }
        return $string;
    }
    echo '<form method="post">';
    $boxes = checkboxes("class", array("Warrior","Mage","Priest","Rogue"));
    echo $boxes;
    echo '<input type="submit">';
?>
```